# Why does R gbm model prediction not match model fit?

Tags: r, machine-learning, predict, r-caret

I'm using caret to fit a gbm model. When I call `trainedGBM$finalModel$fit`, I get output that appears correct.

But when I call `predict(trainedGBM$finalModel, origData, type="response")`, I get very different results, and `predict(trainedGBM$finalModel, type="response")` yields still different results even when origData is attached. To my way of thinking, these calls should yield the same output. Can someone help me identify the issue?

```
library(caret)
library(gbm)

attach(origData)
gbmGrid <- expand.grid(.n.trees = c(2000), 
                       .interaction.depth = c(14:20), 
                       .shrinkage = c(0.005))
trainedGBM <- train(y ~ ., method = "gbm", distribution = "gaussian", 
                    data = origData, tuneGrid = gbmGrid, 
                    trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, 
                                             repeats = 3, verboseIter = FALSE, 
                                             returnResamp = "all"))
ntrees <- gbm.perf(trainedGBM$finalModel, method="OOB")
data.frame(y, 
           finalModelFit = trainedGBM$finalModel$fit, 
           predictDataSpec = predict(trainedGBM$finalModel, origData, type="response", n.trees=ntrees), 
           predictNoDataSpec = predict(trainedGBM$finalModel, type="response", n.trees=ntrees))
```

The above code yields the following partial results:

```
   y finalModelFit predictDataSpec predictNoDataSpec
9000     6138.8920        2387.182          2645.993
5000     3850.8817        2767.990          2467.157
3000     3533.1183        2753.551          2044.578
2500     1362.9802        2672.484          1972.361
1500     5080.2112        2449.185          2000.568
 750     2284.8188        2728.829          2063.829
1500     2672.0146        2359.566          2344.451
5000     3340.5828        2435.137          2093.939
   0     1303.9898        2377.770          2041.871
 500      879.9798        2691.886          2034.307
3000     2928.4573        2327.627          1908.876
```

Comment: Is my guess correct that this is in the `caret` package? It's really inconsiderate to make people guess at this sort of question when all you needed to do was put in `library(_whatever_package_train_came_from)`

Comment: Furthermore, as a separate whinge: Using `attach` is a common source of difficult-to-understand-errors. And you should, of course, have described "origData" more fully.

Comment: What kind of data description is helpful here? I have about 7000 records, with y being fit as a function of 26 features, both factors and numeric.

Answer (score 7):

Based on your `gbmGrid`, only the depth of your interaction will vary between 14 and 20, and the shrinkage and number of trees are fixed at 0.005, and 2000, respectively. The `TrainedGBM` is designed find only the optimum level of interaction as it currently stands. Your `ntrees` calculated from `gbm.perf` is then asking, given that the optimum level of interaction is somewhere between 14 and 20, what is the optimum number of trees based on OOB criteria. Because predictions depend on the number of trees in the model, predictions based on trainedGBM will be use `ntrees = 2000`, and predictions based on `gbm.perf` will use the optimum number of  `ntrees` estimated from that function. This will account for the difference between your `trainedGBM$finalModel$fit` and  `predict(trainedGBM$finalModel, type="response", n.trees=ntrees)`.

To show an example based on the iris data set using gbm as classification rather than regression model

```
library(caret)
library(gbm)

set.seed(42)

gbmGrid <- expand.grid(.n.trees = 100, 
                   .interaction.depth = 1:4, 
                   .shrinkage = 0.05)


trainedGBM <- train(Species ~ ., method = "gbm", distribution='multinomial',
                data = iris, tuneGrid = gbmGrid, 
                trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, 
                                         repeats = 3, verboseIter = FALSE, 
                                         returnResamp = "all"))
print(trainedGBM)
```

giving

```
# Resampling results across tuning parameters:

#  interaction.depth  Accuracy  Kappa  Accuracy SD  Kappa SD
#   1                  0.947     0.92   0.0407       0.061   
#   2                  0.947     0.92   0.0407       0.061   
#   3                  0.944     0.917  0.0432       0.0648  
#   4                  0.944     0.917  0.0395       0.0592  

# Tuning parameter 'n.trees' was held constant at a value of 100
# Tuning parameter 'shrinkage' was held constant at a value of 0.05
# Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
# The final values used for the model were interaction.depth = 1, n.trees = 100
# and shrinkage = 0.05.
```

Finding optimum number of trees conditional on optimum interaction depth:

```
ntrees <-  gbm.perf(trainedGBM$finalModel, method="OOB")
# Giving ntrees = 50
```

If we train the model by varying the number of trees and interaction depth:

```
gbmGrid2 <- expand.grid(.n.trees = 1:100, 
                   .interaction.depth = 1:4, 
                   .shrinkage = 0.05)

trainedGBM2 <- train(Species ~ ., method = "gbm", 
                data = iris, tuneGrid = gbmGrid2, 
                trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, 
                                         repeats = 3, verboseIter = FALSE, 
                                         returnResamp = "all"))

print(trainedGBM2) 

# Tuning parameter 'shrinkage' was held constant at a value of 0.05
# Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
# The final values used for the model were interaction.depth = 2, n.trees = 39
# and shrinkage = 0.05.
```

Note that the optimum number of trees when we vary both the number of trees and interaction depth is fairly close to that calculated for `gbm.perf`.